# Как "перенести значение переменной?

Tags: php

В общем структура скрипта такова:

```
 textarea name="urllist" rows="15" cols="50" style= "background: #696969; resize: none" 
 <?php
тут определённый код где я получаю переменную $res
    ?></textarea>
<p>Х </p>
```

как мне вотнуть значение $res на место Х ?

Comment: Спасибо, работает как часы

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, если Вам помог ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 1):

<p><?php echo $res?></p>

Comment: а фильтровать переменную на HTML теги кто будет?

Comment: изначально ответ бЫл коментарием.Не я его делал полноценным ответом.Фильтровать нужно не спорю,но это уже совсем другой вопрос.Аналогично можно придумать еще несколько условий защиты